# Detect which submit button is used in an Angular2 RC5 Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm creating a prove of concept to see if angular2 can be used in our firm.  I've gotten quite far sofar but now I'm a bit stuck.  I'm consuming a REST resource and like to Get, Post, Put, and Delete by using a form.  This is the form I currently have

```
<section>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit($event)">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><label>Id:</label></td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" formControlName="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><label>Message:</label></td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" formControlName="message" size="50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="getButton" type="submit">GET</button>&nbsp;<input type="text" formControlName="getId"/></td>
                <td><button id="postButton" type="submit">POST</button></td>
                <td><button id="putButton" type="submit">PUT</button></td>
                <td><button id="deleteButton" type="submit">DELETE</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</section>
```

The submit gets registered and sent back to my @Component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import {HelloWorld} from "../../restclient/helloworld/helloworld.model";
import {HelloWorldClient} from "../../restclient/helloworld/helloworld.client";

@Component({
    selector: "helloworld-form",
    template: require('./helloworld-form.html')
})
export class HelloWorldForm implements OnInit{
    fb: FormBuilder;
    form: FormGroup;
    getId : number;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _helloWorldClient: HelloWorldClient) {
        this.fb = fb;
        this.form = fb.group({
            "id": '',
            "message": '',
            "getId": ''
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.controls["getId"]
            .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
                this.getId = value;
        });
    }

    public setData(data : HelloWorld): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            "id": data.id,
            "message": data.message,
            "getId": ''
        });
    }

    public getClicked() {
        this._helloWorldClient
            .GetSingle(this.getId)
            .subscribe((data:HelloWorld) => this.setData(data),
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.log('Fetching single by id ' + this.getId + " completed"));
    }

    public submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
        console.log(target);
        var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
        console.log(idAttr);
        var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
        console.log(this.form);
    }
}
```

Now what I like to do is somehow detect in the submit(event) method which submit button has been pressed.  I had hoped the event would hold that data, but instead it holds the form being submitted, with no clear way of finding the button being clicked.  What is the approved way in Angular2 to do this ?  I've been thinking on adding click events to each button and then saving in a variable on the component which button has been clicked, not sure that is the correct way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td><button id="getButton" type="button" (click)="submit('GET')">GET</button>&nbsp;<input type="text" formControlName="getId"/></td>
<td><button id="postButton" type="button" (click)="submit('POST')">POST</button></td>
<td><button id="putButton" type="button" (click)="submit('PUT')">PUT</button></td>
<td><button id="deleteButton" type="button" (click)="submit('DELETE')">DELETE</button></td>
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the submit from this line then ?

<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit($event)">

Comment: I'd remove it. I expected it to do nothing this way anyway.

Comment: well it works in a way that I now indeed have a mouseevent with the button in it, however the form isn't being submitted anymore so I don't have any of the field values in my component.

tried it like this:

<td><button id="getButton" type="submit" (click)="submit($event,'GET')">GET</button>&nbsp;<input type="text" formControlName="getId"/></td>

Comment: I assumed that you don't want that because of the `event.preventDefault()` in your `submit()` method. but just `this.form.onSubmit()` should give you what you want.

Comment: I've added the event.preventDefault() so the screen wouldn't refresh.  I didn't knew what the deal is with that.  I'm a Java developer by trade they asked me to investigate Angular2 so I'm a bit out of my depths on occasion.

Comment: That's default browser behavior. Angular also provides an `(ngSubmit)="..."` event on the form.

Comment: I was under the impression ngSubmit is for a template driven form ? I'm using a model driven form if I followed the tutorials correctly by using: (submit)="submit($event)" on the form tag

Comment: Not sure about that. Hard to keep track with all the changes recently. Did you try the `this.form.onSubmit()`?

Comment: Unresolved method or function in my typescript module, this.form is of the type FormGroup

Comment: The submit call doesn't do much anyway. It just sets the `submitted` state. I don't think you need the submit to get the values of the inputs. The model should be updated on every change.

Comment: I believe this is the problem with the reactive form method it's not really double binded, you did put me on the way to a "sollution" though I'll post it in an answer.  It's working now, just seems to be more work then you would expect

Comment: You can use `ngModel` to bind that input to a component property but I'm sure the form model itself is updated immediately anyway. You can subscribe to `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe()` to see when the form model gets updated.

Comment: I've posted the sollution I have below tell me what you think ?

Comment: I think that submitting the form should not be necessary and you shouldn't need the hack. If you provide a Plunker to reproduce I have a look.

Comment: Thanks Günter but I'm unfamiliar with plunker and my employer would not appreciate it if I spend to much time with that.  I appreciate all the effort sofar !

Comment: The first `live example` link in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html contains a prepared Angular2 template. Also if you use the new button in Plunker you get Angular2 TS to choose.

Comment: Well I tried making a plunk but can't get it to work

https://plnkr.co/edit/T9yNxIndxKa63Ax7qWsh?p=preview  I've removed most of the unneeded stuff from the code so just the form part remains.  It won't load in the plunker app though.  The whole bootstrapping and library affair is still new to me as java dev

Comment: You removed to much http://plnkr.co/edit/kx17SVfPg1DNiXIgjh66?p=preview

Comment: Thanks this thaught me a lot !

this.form.find('id').value was new to me, I haven't encountered this in any of the tutorials I read (angular.io site is blocked at my workplace !!)

Now I understand why I do not have to submit the form !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer he put me on the right track this is the full sollution

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import {HelloWorld} from "../../restclient/helloworld/helloworld.model";
import {HelloWorldClient} from "../../restclient/helloworld/helloworld.client";

@Component({
    selector: "helloworld-form",
    template: require('./helloworld-form.html')
})
export class HelloWorldForm implements OnInit{
    fb: FormBuilder;
    form: FormGroup;
    getId : number;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _helloWorldClient: HelloWorldClient) {
        this.fb = fb;
        this.form = fb.group({
            "id": '',
            "message": '',
            "getId": ''
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.controls["getId"]
            .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
                this.getId = value;
        });
    }

    public setData(data : HelloWorld): void {
        this.form.get('id').setValue(data.id);
        this.form.get('message').setValue(data.message);
    }

    public submit(event) {
        switch(event) {
            case 'GET' : this.getClicked(); break;
            case 'POST' : this.postClicked(); break;
            case 'PUT' : this.putClicked(); break;
            case 'DELETE' : this.deleteClicked(); break;
            default : break;
        }
    }

    private getClicked() {
        this._helloWorldClient
            .GetSingle(this.getId)
            .subscribe((data:HelloWorld) => this.setData(data),
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.log('Fetching single by id ' + this.getId + " completed"));
    }

    private postClicked() {
        var data : HelloWorld = new HelloWorld();

        data.message = this.form.get('message').value;

        console.log(data);

        /* this._helloWorldClient
            .Add(data)
            .subscribe((data:HelloWorld) => this.setData(data),
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.log('Created resource')); */
    }

    private putClicked() {

    }

    private deleteClicked() {

    }
}
```

with html

```
<section>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><label>Id:</label></td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" formControlName="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><label>Message:</label></td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" formControlName="message" size="50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="getButton" type="button" (click)="submit('GET')">GET</button>&nbsp;<input type="text" formControlName="getId"/></td>
                <td><button id="postButton" type="button" (click)="submit('POST')">POST</button></td>
                <td><button id="putButton" type="button" (click)="submit('PUT')">PUT</button></td>
                <td><button id="deleteButton" type="button" (click)="submit('DELETE')">DELETE</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</section>
```

plunker extract

http://plnkr.co/edit/kx17SVfPg1DNiXIgjh66?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can check which button is clicked by following way.

> I removed (ngSubmit) from form tag

**In .html**

```
<form #postform="ngForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3 style="margin-top:24px;">My Blog</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                    style="float:right; margin-top:24px;" (click)="onSubmit(true, postform)" name="draft">Save as Draft</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                    style="float:right; margin-top:24px;" (click)="onSubmit(false, postform)" name="publish">Publish</button>
            </div>
        </div>
<form>
```

**In .ts**

```
onSubmit(isDraft, postform) {
 // do whatever you want to do 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I haven't worked on angular in two years this question dated from the start of the Angular 2 era